# Make an Internet Shortcut file open Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I currently have an Internet Shortcut file "My Link.url":

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://somewebsite.com
```

I believe Internet Shortcut files are always opened in the *default browser*.

**Does anyone know how to force opening in *Internet Explorer*?**

I have come across `.website` files but Windows Security Shield (is that the right name?) blocks it opening.

**Use case:** *nix server creating a file that will be downloaded to the users desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a normal .lnk shortcut point it to iexplore.exe and supply your url as the first parameter

Comment: I should have mentioned my use case: I want to dynamically create a shortcut on the server and force it to be downloaded. Do you have any experience in creating them? I've had a quick look and I see they're a proprietary binary format.

Comment: If it is a windows server they can be created with vbs and thus also with powershell. The main problem here would be that you would have to assume a default installation path for internet explorer but I think in 99% of all cases no one changes that as the installation is done via Windows Setup/Update. If it is a linux server I sadly have no idea whether it is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a linux server. I think this is a safe strategy considering my user base. If no one comes up with easier solution I will accept this one. Thanks.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using vbs file directly instead of a link. The upside is this is just a text file so it can be easily manipulated in linux. The downside is forcing a download of an executable file from a server might trigger all sorts of antimalware protection mechanisms. This is not really my specialty though so let's hope someone comes up with a solution better fitting for you.